# Error with Jupyter Notebook and Google Cloud

Tags: jupyter, google, cloud

so I integrated my google cloud with the Jupyter Notebook and it seemed to be working as follows:

[I 12:13:51.633 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/kerenb1

[I 12:13:51.633 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:

[I 12:13:51.633 NotebookApp] http://localhost:5000/?
token=63dedf4645de55a797dff864c38721f01740048d93557092

[I 12:13:51.633 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

[C 12:13:51.636 NotebookApp]

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///run/user/1001/jupyter/nbserver-3124-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:5000/?token=63dedf4645de55a797dff864c38721f01740048d93557092
```

But when I did that, it told me that I had to activate my CloudShell and do Web Preview with the port that was given, but I wanted it on my Jupyter Notebook port so I did that and it said:

Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 5000.
Ensure your server is listening on port 5000 and try again.

Anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hey, Are you using a computing instance from the google cloud platform?

Comment: Hey, Yeah. I opened up a google cloud account and have access to global and local (us east 1) resources (Compute Engine API , NVIDIA K80 GPUs).

Comment: Have you made your external IP adress of your instance static? And also under the "VPC network" and "new firewall rule", you can specify what port to listen to.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is static and I also specified the port, 5000. It works cause I entered it previously in order to run the jupyter notebook and I got the confirmation that it is running on that port and even how to access it but when I tried to do that, as I said, it told me that it wasn't listening on that port..

Comment: Hmm right. Can you try to type this into your browser: <static IP>:5000 instead of copy pasting the URL as it is telling you to do. The <> is just a place holder, don't actually type it.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried that. I tried all of the different ways one can open up the notebook and none of them seemed to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. Oddly enough I had another instance regirested before in the same way and it all worked. Unsure what is going on, but suspecting the VM is rejecting to connect for some reason.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Exchange Data Science. It seems like this answer may be better suited as a comment.